# How do I select multiple items from a database using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list, linq-to-sql

So I am selecting from a person table and I need to select the group ids of the groups that the person is in.  How can I do this.

So far, I have:

```
var p = (from p in Context.Person
         join g in Context.Group
         on p.PersonId equals g.PersonId
         select new
         {
             Name = p.Name,
             Age  = p.Age,
             groupIds = ?????
         }
```

So in the group table it will be a primary key of `GroupId` and `PersonId` so I need to select all the group ids.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want a `GroupJoin` rather than a `Join`.  The difference is that rather than having all of the related items flattened into a list of pairs, it groups all of the joined items into a sequence:

```
var query = from p in Context.Person
            join g in Context.Group
            on p.PersonId equals g.PersonId into groups
            select new
            {
                Name = p.Name,
                Age  = p.Age,
                groupIds = groups.Select(g => g.GroupId),
            };
```

Using query syntax the use of the `into` keyword in conjunction with a `join` will result in a `GroupJoin` instead of a `Join`.

Comment: As far as I understand @Pitfall want groupIds but you selected PersonIds . We don't need firstly joining two entityset because ObjectContext entities have primary keys. So they are unique in this context as far as I guess .

Comment: @DavutGürbüz What you select out from the group is trivial enough to change, but yes, I suppose he doesn't want the person ID.  As to whether it would be preferable to do a join versus an inner query as you've done, it would depend a bit on the DB configuration and how it ends up optimizing each query.  It might transform your query into one like this, and if it does they'll be comparable, but if it doesn't then it could end up doing a lot of queries on the group over and over rather than just grouping them in one pass.  You'd need to run them on his data to see which is preferable.

Comment: In fist comment of my answer he says he needs groupID's .  `groupIds = groups.Select(g => g.GroupId),` Missing `,`

Comment: @DavutGürbüz The key point in my eyes from that comment is `which I know how to get based on your example`.  So changing it really isn't a big deal.  What comma do you feel is missing?

Comment: I just meant the final `,` is extra.

Answer (score 2):

I coded on SO's editor. If I understand right you want Person's groups.
Otherwise correct me please.

```
 var p = from p in Context.Person         
     select new
     {
         Name = p.Name,
         Age  = p.Age,
         groups = from g in Context.Group
                  where p.PersonId == g.PersonId
                  select g.GroupId
     };
```

Comment: I need the group Id's which I know how to get based on your example but I get a syntax error right away, everything from "g in...." is underlined in red with multiple errors

Comment: Are you sure? I see `var p = (` can it be `(` this letter cause the error. For Id you may just select ID field as I edited. For whole object you may select g itself.

Comment: @Pittfall Davut was simply missing the `from` keyword to start the inner query.

Comment: @Servy thank you. We have unclosed `(` also. As I said I coded on `SO` s editor. I can't do without VS :)